# use beautiful soup to pull text between two html tags

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

trying to parse all the `<p>` tag after a `<h2>` tag with `id="Content"` and before `<h2>` tag with `id="Tools"`

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2>
   <span class="mw-headline" id="Content">Content</span>
</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2>
   <span class="mw-headline" id="Tools">Tools</span>
</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

to get the string in each

tag

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does that mean you are trying to match the **5** `<p>` tags in between?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findNext` and `findPrevious` on the `span` you target:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2>
   <span class="mw-headline" id="Content">Content</span>
</h2>
<p>foo</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>bar</p>
<h2>
   <span class="mw-headline" id="Tools">Tools</span>
</h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

content = soup.find('span', {'id': 'Content'})
afterSpan = content.findNext('p')
print(afterSpan.text)

tools = soup.find('span', {'id': 'Tools'})
beforeSpan = tools.findPrevious('p')
print(beforeSpan.text)
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
```